# How to databind Enum value to a Boolean value?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

So I have a main form with 3 controls whose `Enable` property I want to control using an enum.

All these controls have a reference to the `Data` that contains the `Enum` value Level.

```
enum Level
{
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Green
}
```

So if it's `Red`, I want the `RedControl` to become enabled, if it's `yellow`, then `YellowControl` becomes enabled, etc.

How do I best do this with minimal code and elegance?

I tried having 3 properties like `IsRed`, `IsYellow`, etc on the `Data` to hook them up. But then I didn't know a way to detect the change of `Level` from those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Flags]
enum Level:int
{
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 4,
    Yellow = Red | Green,
    White = Red | Green | Blue
}

public class myControl : WebControl
{
 public Level color;
 ...
}

public static class extension
{
 public static bool Compare(this Level source, Level comparer)
 {
  return (source &  comparer) > 0; // will check RGB base color
  //return (source & comparer) == source; // will check for exact color
 }
}
```

usage

```
var color = Level.Red;
bool result = color.Compare(Level.Green);

myControl test = new myControl();
test.Enabled = test.Color.Compare(Level.Red);
```

Answer (score 0):

`RedControl.Enabled = ((value & Level.Red) != 0)`

Comment: That doesn't work with data binding, and won't compile [(value & Level.Red) will return an int, not a bool]

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about databinding it... but what about putting enabling code in the property' s set?

ie

```
public YourClass
{
   Level _level;
   public Level level 
   {
      get{ return _level;}
      set 
      {
        _level = value;
        if(_level == Level.Green) { greenControl.Enable = true; //plus disable others }
        if(_level == Level.Yellow) { yellowControl.Enable = true; //plus disable others }
        if(_level == Level.Red) { redControl.Enable = true; //plus disable others }
      }
   }
}
```

that way your property works like normal (and I guess you can databind it but im not really sure) and when it gets changed the controllers will change.

Comment: Thanks but all these control instances contain a reference to Data, and any change in the Data should alert all of them appropriately.

Comment: Then what about rising an event when the data changes, and then in the eventhandler of each control have the control disable itself if it is not the data he likes, and enable itself it is the it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding source class could implement the `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`. I think it's a flexible way to do databinding in windows forms.

Here's one article on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BindBetterINotifyProperty.aspx) showing how to do it. I've haven't analysed it very deeply, though.